# Вывод содержимого переменой с именем которое находится в другой переменной

Tags: python-3.x

Предположим у нас имеется переменная `str`, мы вводим ее значение с клавиатуры:

```
str = input()# Ввели "var1"
```

Дальше мы должны проверить, существует ли переменная с именем `var1`, и если она существует, то к примеру вывести ее содержимое. Иначе сказать, что её нет. Мне очень нужен этот код на Питоне.

Comment: Сделайте словарь, и выбирайте по ключу из него. Обращаться по имени к переменным в Python можно, но не нужно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В комментарии уже сказали, что так делать не надо и лучше использовать нормальный словарь.

Но чисто для справки - есть функция locals(), которая возвращает словарь с переменными и их значениями из локальной области видимости, и аналогичная функция globals() для глобальной области видимости.

Ну а дальше уже в полученном словаре обычным способом можно и проверить существования ключа, и узнать для него значение.

```
var1 = 'test'

s = input() # Ввели "var1"
print(locals()[s]) # Напечатает 'test'
```

Comment: если имя `qual_name = 'a.b.c'`, то `getattr(obj, attr)` можно использовать: [`value = reduce(getattr, qual_name.split('.'), __import__('__main__'))`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/282678/4279) Совершенно верно, что подобного кода следует избегать. В зависимости от конкретной задачи вероятно более идиоматичные решения существуют.

Answer (score 0):

`dir()` возвращает список переменных, т.е.:

```
if s in dir():
```

P.S. не используйте str, это имя стандартного класса!